# How to boost suggestions by doc count using Nest Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, autosuggest

I have **product** index and I have the following properties :

```
public class ProductType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description{ get; set; }

    public IList<string> ProductAttributes { get; set; }

    public CompletionField Suggest { get; set; }
}
```

and when indexing new product I do the following:

```
productType.Suggest= new CompletionField
        {
            Input =product.ProductAttributes.Select(x => x).ToList(),
            Weight = 10
        };
```

How can I boost suggestions depending on how many times that attribute occurs inside product index(the higher document counts that attribute exists the higher boosted one)?

**PS:**

Here is the query I use for auto-complete:

```
GET product/producttype/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "attribute-suggestions": {
      "prefix": "c",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest"
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "id",
      "title",
      "productAttributes"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

If I have the attribute **Cpu** inside 8 products and the attribute **Camera** inside 5 products I want the above query to boost Cpu over Camera.

Comment: It's not possible to do this with Completion Suggester. Completion Suggester only offers a single `weight` to determine order

Comment: @RussCam So could you please tell me an example of the weight parameter and whether is a static value(at indexing time) or could we bind it to the value of a field inside the same index ??

Comment: It's a single value supplied at index time. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#indexing. You can make it the same value as a field at indexing time, but only the `weight` field is used for ordering

Comment: It's possible to perform more complex relevancy scoring, and implement your own: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html. This cannot be used with completion suggester however, which is focused on _fast_ search as you type autocompletion functionality